# ANSI coloring in emacs start-process output buffer

Tags: buffers, process

I am running a process from within emacs which uses ANSI color codes in its output.

I'm using `start-process` to create the process, and provided a custom buffer name for the process's output

```
(start-process "foo" "*Foo*" foo-command foo-args)
```

If I open `*Foo*` buffer, the ANSI color codes are printed in their raw format to the buffer

```
^[[36msome output message^[[m
^[[1;35msome output message^[[m
^[[1;34msome output message^[[m
```

I see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408008/955273) it is possible to add colorization to a buffer; however I'm unsure as to how to do it with a buffer created using `start-process`

Is it possible to convert those ANSI color codes to colorised output in my `*Foo*` buffer?

Comment: Please do not post the same question here and to StackOverflow. Choose one. Thx.

Comment: @gilles the linked duplicate is from 2015 and doesn't have a relevant answer

Comment: Yes, but it's still a duplicate: any answer to one question answers the other question. Duplicate doesn't mean “already has an answer”, it means “any answer would apply”.

Comment: @Gilles I acknowledge that, however, don't you think age has an impact on the likelihood of a question being answered? I would say there is more likelihood of someone seeing an unanswered question come up in their feed and answering it, than there is of someone excavating a 2 year old unanswered question. I also think the likelihood of someone coming to this question, seeing the fact it's marked as a duplicate, and following the link to post an answer there is significantly lower than had it been left open.

Comment: But if the questions are not marked as duplicate, then you halve the chances that someone will answer yours. Marking duplicates as such helps to get answers.

Comment: @Gilles, ok, I accept that. I guess both situations apply. I do believe closing a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question hampers getting an answer. This is probably a discussion best suited for meta.

Comment: @SteveLorimer I just added another answer to that old question. Hope it can help.